# Erro ao trazer um Dado de Registro para um label

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Oi, Estou tentando trazer para um `Label` um dado de registro do Banco de dados, Por exemplo:
quando a pessoa selecionar o produto no `ComboBox` aparecia o preço do produto no `label`

Porem, creio que não estou acertando na questão dos códigos, se alguém puder dar uma luz

codigo usado:

```
private void cbxPeca_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strSelect = "SELECT Preco FROM Produto WHERE Preco LIKE (@Preco)";
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=ProdPacote; Uid=root; pwd=1234;"))
        {
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSelect, conn);
            //Passagem por parâmetros.
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@preco", cbxPeca.Text + "%");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "Preco");
            label4.Text = ds.Tables["Preco"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: `label4.Text = ds.Tables["Preco"]` você está tentando colocar um objeto `Tables` no label? Teria de ser o valor da coluna numa linha, algo como `label4.Text = ds.Tables["Preco"].Rows[0]["nomedacoluna"]`

Comment: na verdade eu queria puxar essa coluna(Preço) da tabela produto pra uma variavel, mas resolvi tentar puxar pra um `label` pra testar primeiro

Comment: no modo como você mostrou a parte do `ds.Tables["Preco"].Rows[0]["nomedacoluna"]` eu coloquei como `ds.Tables["Preco"].Rows[0]["Preco"]` porém fica com erro (aquela linha vermelha em baixo)

Comment: precisa ver qual erro está, passa o mouse e da uma olhada. eu chutaria que é uma conversão de tipo, talvez por um `.ToString()` ao final resolva, mas antes é preciso saber se retornou alguma coisa, depois verifique se o `Rows` tem algum retorno

Comment: Deu certo, Sumiu os erros, porem ainda não aparece no `label` o preço do produto quando seleciono o nome do produto no `ComboBox`

Comment: fui tentar passar usando esse código `label4 = passando.ToString();` porem ele fala que não pode converter implicitamente tipo `string` em `system.windows.forms.label`

Answer (score 4):

Tenta assim:

```
DataTable ds = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(ds, "Preco");
        if (ds.Rows.Count>0 )
            label4.Text = ds.Rows[0]["Preco"];
```

Comment: coloquei, mesmo assim não compilou fica com aquela linha vermelha no `ds` e na parte `ds.Rows[0]["Preco"];`

Comment: usa datatable em vez de dataset

Comment: eu dei um ctrl C e ctrl v no código mas mesmo assim não compilou